# Using SimpleJdbcCall with Array as IN parameter (DB2)

Tags: java, stored-procedures, db2, spring-jdbc

I have created a stored procedure with Array of ROW type as IN parameter and able to call it using JDBC (Java 1.6)
Code is below

```
//Create Array Product List
Struct[] productList = new Struct[1];
Object[] customObject = new Object[]{"Fruits"};
productList[0] = con.createStruct("ProductRow", customObject);

// Create product Response List 
Struct[] responseList = new Struct[1];
customObject = new Object[]{new Integer(1), new Integer(2)};
responseList[0] = con.createStruct("ResponseRow", customObject);

Array products = con.createArrayOf("ProductRow", productList);
Array responses = con.createArrayOf("ResponseRow", responseList);       


// Prepare the call statement 
CallableStatement callStmt = con.prepareCall("CALL SP_create(?, ?)"); 

// Set IN parameters 
callStmt.setArray(1, products); 
callStmt.setArray(2, responses); 

// Call the procedure 
callStmt.execute();
```

Any idea how to do the same with SimpleJdbcCall ?
I am using Spring 2.5 and DB2 9.7 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out finally. I am pasting sample Code for it.

```
Map<String, Object> in = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        in.put("products", new AbstractSqlTypeValue() {
            @Override
            protected Object createTypeValue(Connection con, int type, String typeName) throws SQLException {
                Struct[] productList = new Struct[1];
                Object[] customObject = new Object[]{"Vegetables"};
                productList[0] = con.createStruct("ProductRow", customObject);

                Array products = con.createArrayOf("ProductRow", productList);
                return products;
            }
        });
```

Comment: I'm doing it exactly like this but getting an exception: `Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlFeatureNotSupportedException: [jcc][t4][10181][12052][4.11.77] Method createStruct is not supported. ERRORCODE=-4450, SQLSTATE=0A504` I'm using spring version 4.2.2 and DB2 version 9.7.3.